# Clickable link in edit control

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi

I'm looking for a not-extremely-difficult way to have a clickable link in my multiline edit control.

Does Rich Edit control have this functionality?

Or would I have to write my own control?
And if I did, would the easiest way to just hit test the text? Or create sub syslink32 controls and move their position accordingly. (example code would be much appreciated.)

I'm also willing to replace the edit control completely with an alternative, as long as it doesn't have to much unneeded functionality. (i don't need an entire html viewer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A native edit control does not support this. A RichEdit control does however, either with an RTF link or auto detected links in text.